# Display Multiple Images in Laravel Datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

I am trying many times to show multiple images in datatables, but it always failed. It's only display single image.

**Images in database**

```
[{"name":"_MG_2288 (1).jpg","path":"public\/product_images\/\/mKBWAFw7ZYgVqvz1lrxrEA5PYbal1EqqKm9jEx0F.jpg"},{"name":"555dca050423bda8418b4567.jpeg","path":"public\/product_images\/\/QnYnO9SfA9JJIu7wm0rxJOIJog6txmED8pdiZ4nM.jpg"}]
```

**Controller**

```
$data = \App\Product::latest()->get();

        return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('photo', function ($product) {
                foreach (json_decode($product->product_photo) as $picture) {
                    $pict = '<img src="/reference/eureka/storage/app/' . $picture->path . '" style="height:120px; width:200px"/>';
                    return $pict;
                }
            })
            ->rawColumns(['photo'])
            ->make(true);
```

**View**

```
{
                data: 'photo',
                name: 'photo',
                render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                    return data;
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

in controller save like this

```
        if($request->hasfile('product_image'))
        {

            foreach($request->file('product_image') as $product_image)
            {
                $name=$product_image->getClientOriginalName();
                $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/products/');
                $product_image->move($destinationPath, $name);

                $product_images[] = $name;
            }

            $post->product_image = $product_images;

        }
```

in view if returning on a carousel use slider and get images with their indexes

```
            <div class="w3-white w3-text-grey w3-card-4" >

                <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">


                        @foreach($data->product_image as $slider)

                            <div class="carousel-item {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}" width="250" height="300">

                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{asset('uploads/products/' . $slider)}}" width="250" height="300" alt="{{$data->product_name}}">

                            </div>

                        @endforeach


                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="w3-container" style="text-align: center">
                </div>
            </div><br>
```

Comment: that is my way of getting all images to a view BUT shows them one at a time... i don't know whether you wanted to show case them like a gallery, but for one at a time, that works just fine.